# How can I implement a working return function in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

So basically, I have a main menu function.
The user makes a choice in this menu which is tied to a variable.
The main menu function then calls that function.
The user chooses a product and its amount there.

So it works until here.

Then after the user enters everything, I want the user to stay in that main menu
until they choose to return to the main menu which is represented by the choice variable.

```py
def main_menu(choice=0):
    while True:
        choice = int(input(“Make a choice: “))
        if choice==1:
            dishes()
        if choice==2:
            desserts()
        if choice==3:
            break

def dishes(choice=0):
    print(“1) Buy a dish”)
    print(“2) Go to main menu”)
    choice = int(input(“Make a choice: “))

    if choice==1:
        # Select which dish to buy
        # Select product amount etc.
    if choice==2:
        return choice

def desserts(choice=0):
    print(“1) Buy a dish”)
    print(“2) Go to main menu”)
    choice = int(input(“Make a choice: “))

    if choice==1:
        # Select which dish to buy
        # Select product amount etc.
    if choice==2:
        return choice

main_menu(choice)
```

I don’t want to create a recursion because I cannot terminate the program when I do that.
I want to first call a function from the main menu. Then the function should return a value
to the main menu but should not call itself again. The main menu function should continue
calling that function until the user decides not to. How do I make this work?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your main menu code?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], not vague descriptions of your code and what it is doing

Comment: I added an example for you to check

Comment: Move the first `choice` line so that i'ts inside the `while`.

Comment: I don’t want to make them re-enter. They should stay in the menu they entered until they choose to exit.

Comment: And change lines like `dessert()` to something like `product, quantity = dessert()` (choose a variable name that makes sense). You could use a dictionary to store the product selection and the associated quantity. You may want to return `None, 0` for the go to main menu options and test for `None` before you try to add the entry to the dictionary (or use `try`/`except` or use some value other than `None`.

Comment: "The main menu function should continue calling that function until the user decides not to."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would refactor the submenus into a `while` loop:

```py
def dishes():
    while True:
        print(“1) Buy a dish”)
        print(“2) Go to main menu”)
        choice = int(input(“Make a choice: “))

        if choice==1:
            # Select which dish to buy
            # Select product amount etc.
        if choice==2:
            break

    return # return a value if that's part of the program
```

Also, I notice that the quotes are "smart" quotes, which python doesn't recognize as regular quotes (not sure if that's just a copy/paste issue with Stack Overflow).

Comment: Thank you! I can’t upvote yet but I appreciate it.